# ASP.NET MVC generate url with different culture parameter by ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have several url patterns as follows in the Route:

```
{lang}/package/{packageID}
{lang}/package/{packageID}/Edit/{partNumber}
...
```

There's a footer in layout.cshtml, the footer provides different culture links for users to change the language of the website. When the user click the link, I hope it can change the language and stay in the current page, so I render the link by Razor like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("English", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], new { lang = "en-us"}, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Traditional Chinese", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], new { lang = "zh-tw"}, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Japanese", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], new { lang = "ja-jp"}, null)
...
```

But there is a problem is that I need to pass other parameters which I mentioned above to the page accordingly to keep users staying in the current page.

How could I achieve in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET MVC will [automatically reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15483451/11683) route segments from the current request if they occur earlier than the segment for which you are explicitly providing a value. If you could make your `{lang}` segment the last in the route, what you want would happen automatically.

Comment: @GSerg Thnaks for your comment, but it doesn't seem like a good way to do this, It will actually work in this scenario. However it would be a constraint on the url pattern, every pattern needs to put the {lang} at the end, and also make assumptions about the order in which users make requests. But this is a hint, if I still cannot find other solutions, I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an extension method as an helper for the creation of language-dependent links:

```
public static class LanguageExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary ForLang(this RouteValueDictionary dict, string lang)
    {
        var cloned = new RouteValueDictionary(dict);
        cloned["lang"] = lang;
        return cloned;
    }
}
```

Now you may use it in this way:

```
@Html.ActionLink("English", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], ViewContext.RouteData.ForLang("en-us"), null)
```

Comment: Thanks, this way is simple and clear, it's close to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());` to return to take users back to the page they were at and not have to worry about passing the parameters again.

The flow would be:

1. User clicks on a link like `@Html.ActionLink("English", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], new { lang = "en-us"}, null)`
2. You change the language in the controller's action method
3. Take user back to the page they were on by calling `return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());` from the same action method

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for your answer, I've tried this way before posting this question, it works. But I wonder if there's a way better than redirect, because it needs to take more time to do another navigation.